# How do you enable shuffle on the Spotify Android app?

Tags: spotify

I have been unable to find where shuffle is enabled in the Spotify Android app. Does it have the ability to shuffle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When playing a song you open/slide the tab (sliding drawer) at the bottom center, which displays the album cover and play/previous/next buttons. If you click the **info (i) button** for displaying artist/album information there is an option for shuffling.

This option is also available on the options menu, after pressing the [MENU] button, while this sliding drawer is open.